# RHUI 2.1 Error Downloading the repo

Tags: rhel, repository, redhat-satellite

We are facing this error on `RHUI` when downloading the repo.

unable to find any solution on `Red Hat` site there is one [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/228993) which guides us to edit some file for proxy settings. but we done have any proxy settings in our ENV, we are directly connected to internet.

```
Unexpected error caught at the shell level
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhui/tools/shell.py", line 86, in safe_listen
    self.listen(clear=first_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhui/tools/shell.py", line 112, in listen
    Shell.listen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhui/common/shell.py", line 186, in listen
    item.func(*args, **item.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhui/tools/screens/sync.py", line 201, in repo_sync
    repos = self.pulp.repos_with_sync_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rhui/tools/pulp_api.py", line 288, in repos_with_sync_status
    history_entry = history_list[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image]